# Why is find returning . but not ..?

Tags: find

Let's assume that I move to an empty directory at the following path: `/home/user/dir`

If I execute: `find . ! -name "*.txt"` the result is:

```
.
```

But if I execute `find /home/user/dir ! -name "*.txt"` I get no results.

Why does find have this behavior? Where is it specified?

Moreover, why `..` is not included?

Comment: No results? `find /home/user/dir ! -name "*.txt"` should print at least `/home/user/dir` itself.

Comment: If you run do `find ..`, it will return `..` if it matches the selection criteria just like `find any-other-file`.

Comment: Practically, if `..` was considered to be a name within `.`, then every `find` would recurse all the way back up to `/`, because every directory (including '/' itself) contains a `..`.

Answer (score 5):

[Find is not supposed to print the `.` and `..` entries it encounters during the search of the directory tree](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html). They would not be useful, in any way. If you have it start at `.`, it does print that, though.

> The *find* utility shall recursively descend the directory hierarchy from each file specified by *path*, [...]
> all pathnames for other files encountered in the hierarchy shall consist of the concatenation of the current path operand, a  if the current path operand did not end in one, and the filename relative to the path operand. **The relative portion shall contain no dot or dot-dot components**, no trailing <slash> characters, and only single <slash> characters between pathname components.

With `find ./foo`, a pathname like `./foo/bar/hello.txt` could be found, there, `./foo` would be the current path operand, the `/` added in the middle, and `bar/hello.txt` would be the relative part.

`find /home/user/dir ! -name "*.txt"` should print at least `/home/user/dir` since `dir` does not match `*.txt`. (It should of course also print any other files with names that don't end in `.txt`). If you did `find /home/user/dir -name "*.txt"` without the negation instead, `/home/user/dir` would not be printed since it doesn't match the condition.